# MySQL trigger is hanging from command line

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a mySQL trigger on database table. When the table is updated from an application which connects to the database through PHP the trigger fires perfectly and updates. However, if i try to update a row in that table using the mySQL command line in phpMyAdmin then the database just seems to hang? I can't for the life figure out whats causing it, or how to even debug this. Heres the trigger if anyone can see anything obvious (or even how to make it more efficient, as triggers are new to me!)!

thanks in advance!

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `t_crewstatusupdate`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `t_crewstatusupdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `crewcallouts`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE taxmultiplier INT;
    SET taxmultiplier = ( SELECT t1.taxmultiplier 
                          FROM entities t1, callouts t2 
                          WHERE t1.entityid=t2.entityid 
                            AND t2.calloutid=NEW.calloutid
                        );
    IF NEW.status != OLD.status THEN
      UPDATE callouts 
        SET status = CASE ( SELECT MIN(status) 
                            FROM crewcallouts 
                            WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid
                          ) WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                            WHEN 2 THEN 2 
                            WHEN 3 THEN 4 
                            WHEN 4 THEN 4 
                            WHEN 5 THEN 4 
                            WHEN 6 THEN 4 
                            WHEN 7 THEN 7 
                     END 
        WHERE calloutid=new.calloutid;
    END IF;
    UPDATE calloutstats 
      SET netcrewcost = ( SELECT SUM(get_gross_amount(
                                        ( SELECT calloutdate 
                                          from callouts 
                                          WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid
                                        ),
                                        ( SELECT starttime 
                                          from callouts 
                                          WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid
                                        ),
                                        (workhours + extrahrs),
                                        crewrate,
                                        1, 
                                        IFNULL(travelhours,0)  )
                                    ) 
                          FROM crewcallouts 
                          WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid
                        ),
           grosscrewcost = ( SELECT SUM(get_gross_amount((SELECT calloutdate from callouts WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid),(SELECT starttime from callouts WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid),(workhours + extrahrs),crewrate,1, IFNULL(travelhours,0))
                         * taxmultiplier) 
                             FROM crewcallouts 
                             WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid
                           )        
      WHERE calloutid=NEW.calloutid;
  END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Perhaps you have the setting `AUTOCOMMIT = OFF` in your command line envirorment. Have you tried to do `COMMIT` after the `UPDATE`?

Comment: tried that, I get error - #1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Comment: I didn't mean that you put that `COMMIT` in the trigger code. After updating your table.

Comment: I supposed that the trigger is defined without errors. Correct?

Comment: sorry, ok so I tried this in the update statement - UPDATE  `crewcallouts` SET `updatestats`=3 WHERE `crewcalloutid`=3;
Commit;

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean about 'defined without errors'..

Comment: So, what happened when you run the `UPDATE crewcallouts SET updatestats=3 WHERE crewcalloutid=3; Commit;` Did the trigger fire?

Comment: And disregard my previous question about error, you already say that *"the trigger fires perfectly through PHP"*, so it has been defined fine.

Comment: It appears that the trigger doesn't fire. The update to the table occurs alright, but then the database engine just seems to hang. When I reboot the server the table update is done but the updates from the trigger are not.

Comment: It seems that it fires but it takes a lot of time to complete. Quite complex logic in there. Multiple nested Selects, functions.

Comment: true, the logic is complex - but when the table is updated from the php code, the trigger fires and completes without any noticeable delay, yet updating the table via command line (with same update) it just hangs. bizarre!